# OR and AND Syntax in If condition

Tags: iphone

I want to save all sound files in one array like .caf, .avi ,.mp3.. How can I check OR condition for this.I am confused about syntax.

```
#define kSoundFileExtension @"caf"
#define kSoundfileExtnesion @"mp3"

    if ([fileName rangeOfString:kSoundFileExtension].location != NSNotFound) {
                [self.soundFiles addObject:fileName];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for **OR** :

```
if (([fileName rangeOfString:kSoundFileCAFExtension].location != NSNotFound) ||
([fileName rangeOfString:kSoundFileMP3Extension].location != NSNotFound)) {
```

This is for **AND** :

```
if (([fileName rangeOfString:kSoundFileCAFExtension].location != NSNotFound) &&
([fileName rangeOfString:kSoundFileMP3Extension].location != NSNotFound)) {
```

In **first case** either of two needs to fulfill the condition and in **second case** both need to fulfill the condition.

Comment: Though in real life, you probably would never want to check that a file had BOTH a .mp3 and a .caf extension

Comment: I sceond you andy. Was just differentiating both concepts :)

Answer (score 3):

You would need to give each extension a different identifier, and then check for both, like this:

```
#define kSoundFileCAFExtension @"caf"
#define kSoundFileMP3Extension @"mp3"

if (([fileName rangeOfString:kSoundFileCAFExtension].location != NSNotFound) ||
    ([fileName rangeOfString:kSoundFileMP3Extension].location != NSNotFound)) {
            [self.soundFiles addObject:fileName];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *exts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"caf",@"mp3",nil];

for(NSString *ext in exts) {
    if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:ext]) {
        [self.soundFiles addObject:fileName];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to add a break inside the if statement like this :

NSArray *exts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"caf",@"mp3",nil];

for(NSString *ext in exts) {
    if (([fileName rangeOfString:ext].location != NSNotFound) {
        [self.soundFiles addObject:fileName];
        break;
    }
}

Comment: Done. Also, unrelated to this question, but it may be better to use `NSString`'s `pathExtension` instead of `rangeOfString` to check the file extension.